# How to covert xml to class for windows phone 8.1...?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, xmlserializer

I need to convert an XML to C# classes to be used in Windows phone 8.1 app. And then I need to de-serialize the xml from the code to object of the class.

In Desktop apps, I could do it using xsd.exe. But when I copy the .cs file generated to windows phone 8.1 app, its showing errors on

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
```

and also in the code to deserialise data

```
Stream fs = new FileStream(filepath,FileMode.Open);
```

Its not able to recognise FileStream, even after adding System.IO;

How to achieve the same in windows phone 8.1..?

Comment: which visual studio version you are using ?

Comment: Visual studio 2013 Express with update 3 for Windows

Answer (score 0):

Steps to convert `XML` to equivalent `class` structure:

1) copy your xml content.

2) add new class file in your project and delete all of its content.

3) Visual Studio Menu Bar-> Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes

snapshot:

[image]

reference: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11317/From-XML-to-Strong-Types-in-C